# The path `/app/include/engine` does not exist. (Bundler::PathError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, bundler, rails-engines

I am dockerizing my rails app with the mountable engine. But I am constantly getting one error while running the image `` The path `/app/include/engine` does not exist ``.

The image is successfully built but while running `docker-compose up` it throws an error of the path.

Below I am attching my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
COPY . .
RUN mkdir -p /app/include/engine
RUN git clone git@github.com:engine/engine.git /app/include/engine
RUN ls
RUN ls /app/include/engine
RUN DISABLE_SSL=true gem install puma -v 3.6.0
RUN bundle check ||  bundle install

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db: 
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root@123
        MYSQL_DATABASE: prod
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root@123
    ports:
        - "3307:3306"
  app: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}
    volumes: 
        - ".:/app"
    ports: 
        - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - db
    environment:
        key: value
```

I have also included my engine path in `Gemfile` and followed all the steps in mounting engine

```
# engine
gem 'api', path: 'include/engine'
```

It works fine in the local environment but it gives me an error in docker.

Can someone please help what I m missing somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it because of this line

```
  volumes: 
    - ".:/app"
```

This mounts your local dir inside the container when starting overwriting existing data already in the image. This means everything in `/app` is replaced with data from your local machine including your engine `/app/include/engine`.

To fix this you need to have this engine cloned in your local folder so it is available when starting the container. An other option is to clone the engine outside `/app` for example in `/tmp` or whatever you like.

Comment: So if i clone outside of /app any changes in docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Nope, just rebuild the image and point to the new path in `Gemfile`

Comment: why change the path in `Gemfile` if I make new dir `include/engine` outside /app